# Shutting down a Python environment orderly

Tags: python, multithreading, exit

The obvious ways I can think of to make a Python environment exit, is either `sys.exit()`, or `os._exit()`. However, `sys.exit()` doesn't work outside the main thread, and `os._exit()` doesn't run shutdown handlers (e.g. those registered via `atexit.register`). Also, when there are non-daemon threads running, just exiting the main thread (as might be effected through `thread.interrupt_main`, for instance) won't make the rest of the environment shut down, either.

Is there a way to make Python exit from another thread than the main thread, which runs shutdown handlers?

Comment: Note that if someone sent your program SIGKILL or there is a power failure, then atexit would never be run. You should never rely on atexit being run for anything of importance (e.g. those that modifies persistent data). Given that atexit is unreliable, then it becomes clear that any critical cleanups/recovery should always be run the next time the program starts again. In other words, never rely on orderly exits.

Comment: @LieRyan: Naturally, I'm aware of this, but there are cases where it's simply *nice* to clean up after a program if possible, even if it isn't critical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on what you mean by "orderly".

Even if you don't have any non-daemonic threads, if you call `sys.exit()` from main thread, the other threads will not complete in an "orderly" fashion.  There's no guarantee they will clean up after themselves.

The only really clean way to do it is for the main thread to signal the other threads they should complete and abort (e.g. by setting a flag or an `Event` which they check periodically), wait for them to complete (by `join`ing them), and then return from its `main` function.

Comment: While your point is certainly valid, it should be mentioned that the Java VM actually doesn't care about this. It provides a method of running shutdown handlers and shut down even when non-daemon threads are still running. I was hoping there would exist a similar way to do things in Python.